# Toolbar disappears on iOS 7

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout

Well, I don't know what exactly is happening here, but I'll try to explain to the best of my ability.

This is what it looks like: http://youtu.be/_zbRnYVS6yA

So I constructed a WebView and a Toolbar for my forum view, and then I set some constraints.
I double checked the layering, and yeah, Toolbar is in front.

I came to the conclusion it's the constraints, so I'll need some help. I have little knowledge of Auto Layout and all of it's goodness.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are using a 3.5 inch iPhone simulator. If you use the 4 inch it should work. To make it work on the 3.5 select your View controller and on top select Editor -> Resolve Auto-Layout Issues -> Clear all constraints in view controller. Next remove your toolbar and re-add it.

Comment: I'll need to re-add the constraints

Comment: @x86cam Yes you will need to re-add the constraints and then it should work

Comment: @x86cam You mean the toolbar remained hidden?

Answer (score 0):

On viewDidLoad

self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent=NO;